# MDADM RAID 6 creation on debian/openmediavault

Tags: linux, hard-drive, command-line, bash

I installed openmediavault on my san, which is buggy and I wouldn't be using it unless it was the only one that installs on it since it's older. Im bypassing the UI and am creating the RAID device, and luks on my own. Following this tutorial, https://h3x.no/2011/01/05/howto-create-a-raid6-with-mdadm, it says I need to specify the number of raid and spare drives. I want to use all of them since I have 2 extras and R6 will survive 2 failed drives. How many raid and spare drives should I use? 8r and 4s, or 12 raid?

Thank you

Comment: Depends on your resources and goals.  If you have 4 drives, you could do RAID 6 or RAID 11.  The benefit to RAID 6 is less wasted space.  The benefit to RAID 11 may be technically simpler, and faster, recovery.  If you don't need the space now, and if space can easily be expanded later, then maybe having spares is nicer, just to give yourself flexibility.  In the end, there's a reason why people talk about RAID 0, 1, 5, and 6 but not 2-4.  RAID 0, 1, 5, and 6 all provide advantages over each other, and each is most useful/preferable for some people in some circumstances.  What are your goals?

Comment: I'd like to be able to recover my data and have it encrypted. Raid 6 is common and can withstand 2 drives dying. I actually went ahead and ran the command specifying 2 spares. It completed and didn't blow up thankfully! :) are the spares hot spares that will jump in and replace a drive if it fails?

Comment: I'd recommend against hot spares with parity raid.  You want to have the ability to manage the rebuild  (timing, backing up, load balancing if possible) and rebuild when you are ready mostly due to the possible URE.  I would recommend you have a drive ready for a rebuild, but do not let the controller automatically manage the rebuild without you making sure all is in order first.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you! Open media vault is too buggy so I'm just going to reinstall with centos 7 and make encrypted raid and all the backup jobs manually. I appreciate the answers